# What is the APT line for the Sourceforge main repository?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

What is the correct APT line for the main Sourceforge repository?

The reason I want it is to add Sourceforge to the sources.list.  Too many of the lesser known/used packages don't make it through Mint's default repositories fast enough.

Comment: telling us more info would be helpful, such as which distro you're using. (linux mint is vague, as we do not know the version.)

Comment: I'm running Mint 13 AMD64, with MATE (if that matters).

Comment: There is simply no single unified repository that exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, alas, SourceForge does NOT have a master deb repo. (Yes, I am SF staff.)

Answer (score 2):

Does sourceforge *have* a debian repository? What is its address? You cannot simply add a website that hosts software projects as a debian repository, it needs to be formatted in a very specific way. I have never heard of sourceforge offering a debian repo and I really really doubt that it does. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Assuming that sourceforge does indeed have a debian repository, the general format of the deb line would be:

```
deb http://sourceforge.repo.url <debian distro> <list of repo categories>
```

For example, for debian-multimedia, my line is:

```
deb http://www.debian-multimedia.org sid main non-free
```

That means I want the packages for `sid` that are in the `main` and `non-free` categories. So, for you and the hypothetical sourceforge debian repo, it would be something like:

```
deb http://repo.sourceforge.net maya main
```

"Maya" is your distribution, you would have to check the actual repository URL to see what sub categories it has apart from main.

---

Update:

I think I see what you mean. Many specific sourcefourge projects offer debian repos that are hosted on the sourceforge servers. These are *not* "sourceforge debian repos" though, they are repositories for specific projects.

---

Update 2, in answer to your comment:

OK, no there will not be a master repo. First of all, the vast majority of projects will not have a debian package available. Also, maintaining/setting up a repo is not trivial. Especially if you consider that you need different repos/sub repos for the various debians and debian based distros. Then how about rpm-based distros? No, what you will have are various minor repos maintained by the project's authors.

As for your second question, yes the distro you are using is important. Software packages like .debs or .rpms contain the software in question and also a list of other software that it depends on. A .deb for Mint version X will require the specific versions of its dependencies that are available for *that* version of Mint/Ubuntu. That is why you cannot blindly install a .deb for say Mint 13 on Mint 10. A lot of the dependencies will not be met.

Comment: that's exactly what I was getting at.  I have previously added repos for a couple projects on Sourceforge.  I figure there has to be a "master" repo.  But searches of Sourceforge's forum's yielded no results.  Is the distro being used even relevant?  I'm most interested in getting updated packages that take a long time to get through testing by the Mint devs.

Comment: @OCDtech, see my updated answer.